# How do I solder this red part in PCB?

Tags: pcb, soldering, wire, pcb-assembly

I am making an arcade stick.

I was making good progress on the right hand side

but now stuck on this red circle bit.

For the RHS I had this socket(?) that I can put solder on easily

But this red circle. The solder does not stick at at all!
even worse, every time I fail it takes off bit of that bright coloured circuit!

My god! hope my PCB is not dead yet!

How do I connect a wire to that red circle? or anywhere on the green region where there is no socket.

[image]

Comment: you need to expose  bare copper before soldering  so a light rub with fine emery paper to get rid of the coating.

Comment: If you still need to use those switches I suggest you put some tape over the gold plating except just where the solder should go. If your solder interferes with the switch it may not work reliably ever again- it cannot realistically be removed once it gets on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow the trace to R2 and solder your wire there instead of to the trace.

The larger pad on R2 will let you solder your wire better.

You can use the same trick on all of your contacts.  Follow the trace to someplace with a regular part and solder your wire there.

---

In response to comments:

Practice and patience.

It does work, and I've done it often.

If R2 is coming unstuck then you are getting things too hot, probably by keeping the iron in contact with the pad too long.  You probably won't damage the part, but may eventually destroy the pads.

You would have the same problem (but worse) soldering to the trace.

---

Try this:

1. Tin your wire, and leave (very) small blob on the tip.
2. Put the solder in contact with the pad of R2, then touch the soldering iron to the pad.  The solder will melt and take a bit of fresh solder.
3. Now remove the iron from the pad and let the solder solidify.
4. Touch the wire to the pad.
5. Put the tip of the iron on the pad.
6. The solder will melt and the wire will enter the puddle of solder.
7. Remove the iron but keep the wire in the puddle.
8. Let the solder cool.
9. Let go of the wire.
10. Finished.

Comment: As JRE said, for this particular solder you can just solder the wire to any end of the resistor located at R2. However this does not mean that you can follow any trace and solder on any component..

Comment: Hello thank you for your prompt answer, that R2 bit has some sort of super tiny resistance chip on it. Can I put solder there? Would it not burn that chip?

Comment: Soldering there will not burn up the resistor.  They stand up well to soldering - that's how they were put there in the first place.  :)

Comment: Thank you.. Still got problem.. R2 chip is too tiny every time I put solder there the wire does not stick and R2 chip becomes loose and I get heart attack..

Comment: I traced back further to locate the large chip pin on the RHS. May I ask what is the purpose of the R1 chip? It crosses 3 different traces. Can I ignore that chip and follow on?

Comment: No. Don't do that.  R1 is behind R2.  It is NOT electically the same point as the spot on your keypad that you want to connect.  In this case, R2 is your only bet.  And make sure to connect your wire to the side of R2 that goes to the keypad.

Comment: Wow.. I did it! you are god sir. I never knew you could attach wire to the side of that super tiny resistor.. Now I need to check if the pad is not dead yet... Thank you for your kind answer.

Comment: I think the wiring in the side of R2 is dead. I connected the other side to the ground but that button does not respond at all. If I put the wire anywhere else it does show responds for other buttons. Is there any way to fix this R2 chip area?

Comment: I dunno.  I can't make sense of your description.  A picture would help.  Maybe a new question?

Comment: If put the wire to the other side of R2 it shows response to the combination of button 2 and 3. But the original side -button 1- does not respond as expected. It "sometimes respond" but in a unpredictable way. respond very late and it "blinks" if you could see what I mean.

I will post new question thank you.

Comment: Hello I posted new question :  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/233747/arcade-stick-pcb-not-working-as-expected