# Arcade stick PCB not working as expected

Tags: pcb, soldering, pcb-assembly

I am using Logitech precision PCB to make an arcade stick.

[image]

I am having a problem in button 1 (green) area.

While I try to solder button 1 via R2, I had a great difficulty - R2 resistor moved every time I tried to solder.

The picture below indicates which side I soldered my wire. I desoldered it to check if it was the button/wire being faulty.

[image]

When it was soldered to R2 the button "sometimes" responded but in a unpredictable way. Not only respond very late and it "blinked" like mad. but now even if I put wire there it does not show any response :

[image]

This is what I get if I move the wire to the other side of R2

[image]

[image]

Any way to get the button 1 working again?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Just soldering a wire to that resistor should not trigger anything, so you must have something at the other side of that wire that does something, and we have not the slightest idea of what it is that it does.Obviously it doesn't close switch 1 though as there is nothing else soldered in that vicinity that could.

Comment: Your second image is fuzzy.  Can you make one that is better in focus?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/CBMM6
I uploaded 3 full sized images to the link above. Sorry about my shitty phone camera. If you need it more in focus I will go and borrow a digital camera

Comment: Yes very strange.. there is one spot on that side where button 1 is always on and when I press the separate button (https://www.focusattack.com/sanwa-obsf-30mm-pushbuttons-black/) I used to connect it actually turns off the signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your previous attempts to solder to the trace at SW1 destroyed the trace from SW1 to R2.  If you are pressing the mechanical button that should close SW1, then it can't really work.

You need to solder a very fine wire (single strand) from R2 to the now unconnected half of SW1.

Also, it appears that the buttons  are on some kind of matrix.  They are not "one active side to ground" but rather "two active sides together."

---

If you are not trying to use the original button, then you need to connect the SW1 side of R2 and the "nose" of D2 to you new button to make it work.  Connecting R2 to ground isn't the same as closing SW1.

Comment: I am connecting a separate button for that (https://www.focusattack.com/sanwa-obsf-30mm-pushbuttons-black/) I don't think I will need to use SW1 if I use separate buttons? I am merely using that PCB to create an arcade stick.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I actually tried connecting button 2 and 4 to the spot circled in the first picture and the button works as expected connecting just single line from SW2/4 and its ground. So likewise button 1 should work just connecting SW1 and its ground no?

Comment: Nope.  The contacts on those switches are mostly in pairs.  most of them don't have a ground.  They have two live connections that the processor drives alernately high and low and looks to see where is gets its output back on an input.  You have to connect your new switch to the two sides of the switch on the board.  For SW1 that is one side of R2 and the nose of D2.  For the others, you will have to look.  Soldering heavy wire like you are using straight to those fine traces is just asking for the trace to be ripped off the board.

Comment: I tried connecting pink ground and R2 and button 1 works now. Perhaps the first picture diagram is wrong?

Comment: Wire it like I said, and you can be ceratin that it will work.  Otherwise, I can't help.  I can't tell where the "pink ground" goes because at one point it changes to the other side of the board.  Just short the contacts on the PCB switches with your new buttons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer you do really seem to know a lot and I thank you for putting your time to this. May I also ask which wire I need to use to connect to the fine trace?

Comment: Use finer wire, but avoid soldering directly to the traces if possible.  I don't know what you've got available for wire, but what you are using is way to heavy for connecting directly to the finer traces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39707/discussion-between-zcahfg2-and-jre).